# SSAS: MDX Calculated Member filtered by a given date

Tags: ssas, mdx

I am struggling to come up with a calculated member in MDX.

The source table looks like below.

```
--------------------------------------
| Status     | Promised Date          |
-------------------------------------- 
| In-process | 2014-09-15 00:00:00.000|
--------------------------------------
| Quotation  | 2014-07-20 00:00:00.000|
--------------------------------------
| In-process | 2014-10-25 00:00:00.000|
--------------------------------------
```

There is a measure which calculates the row count.Say it's called [Measures].[SVC Call Count].

A date will be provided when the user picks up a date from a Date dimension.

The calculated member should return a row count of all svc calls in-process + 14 days prior to the given date.
For example, 2014-10-20 is a given date. In this case, only the first row should be count.
It's straightforward to achieve this in `T-SQL`:

```
SELECT Count(*) 
FROM [SVC Call] 
WHERE 
  CALLSTATUS='In-process' and DATEADD("d",14,Promised Date)<= A given Date.
```

But I am new to MDX and don't know how to do so in MDX. Current attempt as follows:

```
Sum
(
  Filter
  (
        [Service call].[Promised end date].[Promised end date].MEMBERS
      - 
        [Service call].[Promised end date].&[1900-01-01T00:00:00]
    - 
      [Service call].[Promised end date].[All].UnknownMember
   ,
      VBA!Datediff
      ("d"
       ,[Service call].[Promised end date].CurrentMember.MemberValue
       ,LinkMember
        (
          [DATE].[Date].CurrentMember
         ,[DATE].[Year - Quarter - Month - Week - Date]
        ).MemberValue
      )
    >= 0
  )
 ,[Measures].[Service call count]
)
```

Can anyone provide me with advice or tips?

Comment: what `MDX` have you tried so far? StackOver works better if you show your current attempt.

Comment: I have tried as below. SUM(
 Filter(
[Service call].[Promised end date].[Promised end date].MEMBERS-[Service call].[Promised end date].&[1900-01-01T00:00:00]-[Service call].[Promised end date].[All].UNKNOWNMEMBER,
VBA!Datediff("d",[Service call].[Promised end date].CurrentMember.MemberValue
,LINKMEMBER([DATE].[Date].CurrentMember,[DATE].[Year - Quarter - Month - Week - Date]).MemberValue
) >= 0
),[Measures].[Service call count])

Comment: - cool - I've added it to your post - hope you're ok with this.